# Is there a more masculine way to describe a "petite" man?

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

What would you call a man who is short in stature and slight (or wiry) in body?

For clarity, these are not men with dwarfism. I'm also wanting a word that doesn't (or shouldn't) automatically be inferred as an insult to their "manhood."

Comment: 'short' pretty much covers it

Comment: Yikes. Some might consider "short" a bit harsh. Is this a written description, or for everyday engagement?

Comment: As a short guy, short is much better than pussy-footing around it. I'm short, I own it.  Tall people are less intelligent anyway(smirk)

Comment: As Harlan Ellison once said in reply to an offended dwarf, "Hey, I'm five foot two, _I'm_ a little person. _You're_ a midget!"

Comment: If the person is short and wiry and pugnacious you could use a boxing term like "bantamweight" or "flyweight" ... but like all diminutive terms they are sometimes used derisively.

Comment: There really _should_ be a word like "petite" but reserved for masculine types. We may need to turn to the French on this one.

Comment: @christopherm. Wouldn't that just be the masculine _petit_?

Comment: @shoover Pardon, no, I just meant an English word derived from French. Looking. Haven't found one for this case.

Comment: He may not be tall but he's sexy, and charismatic.

Comment: Of less than average stature.  Less than average height.  Of a height more common in the Third World.

Answer (score 4):

How to say *petite* to a man?

You could consider ***nimble***, ***lean*** or ***light-footed***.  Whilst strictly not a descriptor for 'short in stature' they can easily imply this to an excusable degree - especially if looking for a roundabout way to avoid using the word *petite* on a man.

[***lean***](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20lean) will imply thin (especially healthily so) - of containing no excess.

[***nimble***](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20nimble) implies agility, quick and light in movement.

There is also [***trim***](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20trim) which may be suitable for suggesting "of the required size and form".

---

(Tom22's comment worth mentioning about using a boxing term.  You could consult an entry in a table from the following:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_class_(boxing))

Comment: *Lean* and *trim* are things we can all aspire to equally, however tall we are. *Nimble* and *light footed* often give a sense of *surprisingly so for a bit guy*.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the man has a small frame or is small framed.   I would then go on to add other appropriate descriptors that speak of the man's other characteristics.  For example, a man with a small frame can be well built, fit, muscular, well proportioned, slender, etc. You can also describe how the person moves as a way of adding to the picture.

In my opinion, in the United States, there's an unjustified bias against men with smaller build and also, women with a larger build.  I think the antidote, when describing such people in writing, is to use accurate description and avoid terms that carry negative connotation.

I am curious how other cultures without this bias describe men of smaller stature.

Answer (score 2):

*Compact* is not insulting, if anything the opposite and is probably your best bet.

[a compact person is physically small but looks strong](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/compact_1) (macmillan dictionary)

Many of the other suggestions imply either *thin* or *heavily built* more than *short*.

Answer (score 1):

"Bantamweight" is a small weight class in [boxing and other combat sports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bantamweight). Hence referring to a man as a "bantam" would convey small stature along with physical toughness. In the British Army, and particularly during WW1, it [was also used as a label for soldiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bantam_(military)) who were admitted to the army despite being below regulation height.

Answer (score 0):

***He has the body type of a marathon runner***

This article in [The Globe and Mail](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/life/health-and-fitness/fitness/do-you-have-the-body-type-to-run-a-marathon/article586440/), titled *Do You Have the Body Type to Run a Marathon* states that the fastest marathoners are about 5'7" and weigh about 140 pounds.  The article states:

> Running at high speed requires a lot of energy...... All elite
>   marathoners will have as little fat, bone and even muscle as
>   possible.....With less weight to carry, smaller runners are simply
>   lighter on their feet.

As the OP requested, this is a term that cannot be interpreted as an insult to the manhood of the person so described; it is a compliment.

5'7" and 140 pounds may be larger than the OP means by petite, but by today's standards in developed countries, especially for young men, this is a small man.  See [Average Height for Men by Country](http://www.averageheight.co/average-male-height-by-country).  Examples:  UK 5'9.75";  US 5'9.5"; Netherlands 6'0.5"

Answer (score -1):

I think an appropriate adjective would be '*stocky*', or 'well built' which is feasible, but also more vague.

Definition: compact, sturdy, and relatively thick in build

I'm unsure as to whether or not these definitions would encompass their stature although it does the 'wiry' aspect.

**Edit: the definitions I listed were a bit exaggerated in regards to body build so a milder definition would be 'lithe'**

Comment: +1 for "stocky", but that also implies... not skinny? Like, thick but short? If he was short and skinny, that wouldn't work.

Comment: _stocky_ and _wiry_ seem like opposite body types to me.

Comment: I guess 'lithe' could be viable as well, although its definition isn't as precise in comparison to 'wiry'. I think you could try 'lithe', though. It's the first word that came to mind.

Comment: I always thought "lithe" implied being tall?  I don't see anything about height in the dictionary.com definition, but that was always the context I heard it used in-- tall and thin.

Comment: Slight and stocky are not compatible descriptors in my opinion.  Stocky is about proportion of body width to height and doesn't imply shortness in height.